# Unable to retrieve metadata for ApplicationUser. - VS13

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

i am receiving the following error when I choose to generate MVC5 controller with Views using Entity framework:

Unable to retrieve metadata for ApplicationUser. Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets ApplicationUsers and Users can both contain instances of type ApplicationUser"

searching SO , i found this :[same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19888576/vs-2013-controller-scaffolding-fails-for-the-applicationuser-model-multiple-obj) but it has a hack not a solution ..

is it a bug in VS13?

and how can I fix it