# ASP.NET Identity - Multiple object sets per type are not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I got an error using ASP.NET Identity in my app.

> Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets
>   'Identity Users' and 'Users' can both contain instances of type
>   'Recommendation Platform.Models.ApplicationUser'.

I saw a few questions about this error in StackOverflow. All indicate on two `DbSet` objects of the same type. But in my `DbContext` there aren't the same types of `DbSets`. Exception is thrown on `FindAsync()` method during logging in.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
    var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
    if (user != null && user.IsConfirmed)
    {
```

The problem is I don't have two `DbSets` of the same type. My Contexts look like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<RecommendationPlatform.Models.ApplicationUser> IdentityUsers { get; set; }

}
```

and

```
public class RecContext : DbContext
{
    public RecContext()
        : base("RecConnection")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<RecContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<RecContext>());
    }

    public DbSet<Recommendation> Recommendations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Geolocation> Geolocations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Faq> Faqs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<IndexText> IndexTexts { get; set; }
}
```

What could cause this problem? Maybe something connected with in-built ASP.NET Identity functionalities? Anyway, what is `Users` type? I don't have it in my app...

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You do have two `DbSet`s` of the same type.

`IdentityDbContext<T>` itself contains `Users` property declared as:

```
public DbSet<T> Users { get; set; }
```

You're declaring second one in your class.

Comment: Look inside IdentityModel.cs, you will find

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
Inside of this context, VS sometimes adds  DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers

Comment: @VasilValchev when you inheritance from IdentityUser class it contain Users DbSet

Comment: I also got the same error, But I never added this line in IdentityModel.cs. How did it magically came there and started throwing error. I am even uploading my changes in git. How come this line came up magically there. Please guide me. P.S: commeting that line fixes the issue

Comment: How do you solve the problem though? Just deleting the property means it can no longer be accessed.

Answer (score 70):

review this file "ApplicationDbContext.cs", remove the line, generated automatically by scaffold last, should be like this:

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Manager.Models.ApplicationUser> IdentityUsers { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you, now I know the culprit is the scaffolding that the new controller wizard did just now.

Comment: Nice! I never used the scaffold and after used it to build a controller, everything goes wrong! Nice tip bro!

Comment: Just deleting the property means it can no longer be accessed.

Answer (score 11):

This issue can arise from using scaffolding to create a `View`. You probably did something like this: *View > Add > New Scaffold Item... > MVC 5 View > [Model class: ApplicationUser]*.

[image: Add View Screenshot]

The scaffolding wizard added a new line of code in your `ApplicationDbContext` class.

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<RecommendationPlatform.Models.ApplicationUser> IdentityUsers { get; set; }
```

Now you have two `DbSet` properties of the same type which not only causes an exeptions to be thrown in the `FindAsync()` method but also when you try to use code-first migrations.

[image: Exception when using code-first migrations]

Be very careful when using scaffolding or even better don't use it.

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me! Note: if you generated a controller with scaffolding like this then change "ApplicationUser" to "User" in the controller

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I see this problem, I always double check the DbSet. - ESPECIALLY if you are using another language for Visual Studio.

For us who use other language on VS, always double check because the program doesn´t create controllers or models with the exact name. perhaps this should be a thread.. or there is one already and I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Comment the new generated Dbset from identity model class like below

```
// public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<SurveyTool.Models.ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
```