# MVC 5 Multiple object sets per type are not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I get this error when I try to login into my ASP.NET MVC5 with Identity Web Application. This application used to be MVC4 until I upgraded to MVC5 because of Identity. In MVC4 it uses a User.cs class while in MVC5 my ApplicationUser is derived from IdentityUser.

> Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets
>   'ApplicationUsers' and 'Users' can both contain instances of type
>   'RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models.ApplicationUser'.

I read from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343246/asp-net-identity-multiple-object-sets-per-type-are-not-supported) that I needed to remove this line to fix my problem

`public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Manager.Models.ApplicationUser> IdentityUsers { get; set; }`

but after removing it I have multiple errors on 'ApplicationUsers' in my ApplicationUserController.cs saying

> 'ApplicationDbContext' does not contain a definition for
>   'ApplicationUsers' and no extension method 'ApplicationUsers'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'ApplicationDbContext' could be
>   found

[image]

IdentityModels.cs

```
namespace RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser
    : IdentityUser<int, ApplicationUserLogin,
        ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>, IUser<int>
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity>
            GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager)
        {
            var userIdentity = await manager
                .CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            return userIdentity;
        }


        public bool IsAdministrator { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1)]

        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]

        [Column("FirstName")]
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

        public string FullName
        {
            get { return FirstMidName + " " + LastName; }
        }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
        public int DepotID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("DepotID")]
        public virtual Depot Depot { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }
    public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { }
    public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }

    public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<int, ApplicationUserRole>, IRole<int>
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public ApplicationRole() { }
        public ApplicationRole(string name)
            : this()
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }

        public ApplicationRole(string name, string description)
            : this(name)
        {
            this.Description = description;
        }
    }


    public class ApplicationDbContext
        : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int,
        ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        static ApplicationDbContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        public class ApplicationUserStore :
    UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int,
    ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole,
    ApplicationUserClaim>, IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int>,
    IDisposable
        {
            public ApplicationUserStore() : this(new IdentityDbContext())
            {
                base.DisposeContext = true;
            }

            public ApplicationUserStore(DbContext context)
                : base(context)
            {
            }
        }


        public class ApplicationRoleStore
            : RoleStore<ApplicationRole, int, ApplicationUserRole>,
            IQueryableRoleStore<ApplicationRole, int>,
            IRoleStore<ApplicationRole, int>, IDisposable
        {
            public ApplicationRoleStore()
                : base(new IdentityDbContext())
            {
                base.DisposeContext = true;
            }

            public ApplicationRoleStore(DbContext context)
                : base(context)
            {
            }
        }




        public DbSet<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Depot> Depots { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models.ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ApplicationUserController.cs

```
    public class ApplicationUserController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: ApplicationUser
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            var applicationUsers = db.ApplicationUsers.Include(a => a.Department).Include(a => a.Depot);
            return View(await applicationUsers.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: ApplicationUser/Details/5
        public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            ApplicationUser applicationUser = await db.ApplicationUsers.FindAsync(id);
            if (applicationUser == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(applicationUser);
        }

        // GET: ApplicationUser/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.DepartmentID = new SelectList(db.Departments, "DepartmentID", "DepartmentName");
            ViewBag.DepotID = new SelectList(db.Depots, "DepotID", "DepotName");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: ApplicationUser/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Id,IsAdministrator,LastName,FirstMidName,EnrollmentDate,DepartmentID,DepotID,Email,EmailConfirmed,PasswordHash,SecurityStamp,PhoneNumber,PhoneNumberConfirmed,TwoFactorEnabled,LockoutEndDateUtc,LockoutEnabled,AccessFailedCount,UserName")] ApplicationUser applicationUser)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.ApplicationUsers.Add(applicationUser);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.DepartmentID = new SelectList(db.Departments, "DepartmentID", "DepartmentName", applicationUser.DepartmentID);
            ViewBag.DepotID = new SelectList(db.Depots, "DepotID", "DepotName", applicationUser.DepotID);
            return View(applicationUser);
        }

        // GET: ApplicationUser/Edit/5
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            ApplicationUser applicationUser = await db.ApplicationUsers.FindAsync(id);
            if (applicationUser == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.DepartmentID = new SelectList(db.Departments, "DepartmentID", "DepartmentName", applicationUser.DepartmentID);
            ViewBag.DepotID = new SelectList(db.Depots, "DepotID", "DepotName", applicationUser.DepotID);
            return View(applicationUser);
        }

        // POST: ApplicationUser/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,IsAdministrator,LastName,FirstMidName,EnrollmentDate,DepartmentID,DepotID,Email,EmailConfirmed,PasswordHash,SecurityStamp,PhoneNumber,PhoneNumberConfirmed,TwoFactorEnabled,LockoutEndDateUtc,LockoutEnabled,AccessFailedCount,UserName")] ApplicationUser applicationUser)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(applicationUser).State = EntityState.Modified;
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.DepartmentID = new SelectList(db.Departments, "DepartmentID", "DepartmentName", applicationUser.DepartmentID);
            ViewBag.DepotID = new SelectList(db.Depots, "DepotID", "DepotName", applicationUser.DepotID);
            return View(applicationUser);
        }

        // GET: ApplicationUser/Delete/5
        public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            ApplicationUser applicationUser = await db.ApplicationUsers.FindAsync(id);
            if (applicationUser == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(applicationUser);
        }

        // POST: ApplicationUser/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            ApplicationUser applicationUser = await db.ApplicationUsers.FindAsync(id);
            db.ApplicationUsers.Remove(applicationUser);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After you remove that line, can you look for a `Users` property in your context? This property would be a `DbSet` of `ApplicationUser` as well. If you find it, you can just use that in your controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class representation of

```
public class ApplicationDbContext
    : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int,
    ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{...}
```

already has a `Users` property

```
public virtual IDbSet<TUser> Users { get; set; }
```

where `TUser` for you will be `ApplicationUser`.

You need to replace all instance of where you have `db.ApplicationsUsers` to `db.Users`

example:

```
var applicationUsers = db.ApplicationUsers.Include(a => a.Department).Include(a => a.Depot);
```

changes to:

```
var applicationUsers = db.Users.Include(a => a.Department).Include(a => a.Depot);
```

Comment: If I replace all instances of db.ApplicationUsers to db.Users then i get an error on this line `ApplicationUser applicationUser = await db.Users.FindAsync(id);` then I get   `IDbSet<ApplicationUser>' does not contain a defintion for 'FindAsync' and no extension method 'FindAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'IDbSet<ApplicationUser>' could be found.`

Comment: which is correct. IDbSet does not have that async method

Comment: So I need to recreate my Controllers to not have async controllers?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can make your own async extension method to do it async

Comment: That sounds a bit too hard. I don't even know what async does. All I know is that it doesn't waste a thread waiting for another to compute data.

Answer (score 2):

The `IdentityDbContext` class already has a `DbSet<ApplicationUser>` property called `Users`.

So, if your own context class inherits from `IdentityDbContext`, there is no need to add your own `DbSet<ApplicationUser>` property (and in fact, if you do, you will encounter the "multiple object sets" error).

The `Users` property will be available on your own context, so you can just use that instead.

Comment: Don't quite understand what you mean by `The Users property will be available on your own context, so you can just use that instead.` So I remove `public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models.ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }` and use which one?

Comment: It's how inheritance works. Any class that inherits from `IdentityDbContext` will have access to all of its non-private properties. The `IdentityDbContext` class has a non-private `Users` property, which is a `DbSet<ApplicationUser>`. So, when you use your own context (which inherits from `IdentityDbContext`), the `Users` property will be available for your use.

Comment: But after changing 1db.ApplicationsUsers1 to 1db.Users` I get this  `IDbSet<ApplicationUser>' does not contain a defintion for 'FindAsync' and no extension method 'FindAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'IDbSet<ApplicationUser>' could be found`

Comment: You can just use the non-async version if that's okay with you. You might want to look at using the `UserManager` class as well.

Comment: Non-async controllers?

Answer (score 0):

when I do this, this view need the two new lines:

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Residual.Models.Residual.Rclient> Rclients { get; set; }
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Residual.Models.ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
```

and if i use only my Rclientes i couldnt use the full view.