# ASP.NET MVC error when using CRUD

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating MVC application, trying to get records out of database using CRUD, but then I get this error

> "Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets
>   'ApplicationUsers' and 'Users' can both contain instances of type
>   'WebApplication1.Models.ApplicationUser'."

I can't find "Users" property used anywhere, and when I replace all "ApplicationUser" with "User", I get this error:

> "Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets
>   'Users' and 'Users' can both contain instances of type
>   'WebApplication1.Models.ApplicationUser'."

I'm stuck and I have no idea what to do...

Edit:

```
    namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string DoB { get; set; }
        public string Additional { get; set; }


        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }




    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<WebApplication1.Models.ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Please, post some code withof your `dbContext`. are you inherit from `IdentityDbContext<T>`?

Comment: Hello, please check my edit, and tell me if that was what you need?

Comment: please have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24343319/5331361)

Comment: Sorry, I think I've looked at this question, but as I'm very new to all of this, I couldn't understand what to do. Could you please tell me, which part do I need to remove? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove this line:

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<WebApplication1.Models.ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

Because when you inherit from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` your class already have property `DbSet<T> Users` where `T` is class specified by you (`ApplicationUser`)

**Edit**: For now to access users dbset use `dbContext.Users`.

If you want to use `dbContext.ApplicationUser` create wrapper property in `ApplicationDbContext`:

```
public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser
{
  get { return Users; }
  set { Users = value; } 
}
```

Comment: After removing the said line, im getting 7 errors like 
`CS1061 'ApplicationDbContext' does not contain a definition for 'ApplicationUser' and no extension method 'ApplicationUser' accepting a first argument of type 'ApplicationDbContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  `