# Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets IdentityUsers'and Users can both contain instances of type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

The object sets IdentityUsers'and Users can both contain instances of type net

But I tried to create a many to many relation like this tutorial shows [getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

But I got this error =>
`Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets 'IdentityUsers' and 'Users' can both contain instances of type 'bugs_b_gone.Models.ApplicationUser'`.

**I have a property in the project class so the user who has created the project is the admin
But now that admin has to create users and assign it to the project**

```
public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    //public int AdminID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Title cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
    [Column("Title")]
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }


    //public int MemberID { get; set; }

    //public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Bug> Bugs { get; set; }

    // veel op veel
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> User { get; set; }
}
```

**Now the IdentityModel.cs**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Bug> Bugs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Bug> Bugs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });


        //modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

        /*  modelBuilder.Entity<AssignedTo>()
          .HasOptional(f => f.AssignedToID)
          .WithRequired(s => s.Bug);*/

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
            .HasMany(c => c.User).WithMany(i => i.Projects)
            .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("ProjectID")
                .MapRightKey("Id")
                .ToTable("ProjectUser"));

    }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<bugs_b_gone.Models.ApplicationUser> IdentityUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<bugs_b_gone.Models.ApplicationUser> IdentityUsers { get; set; }
```

`IdentityDbContext` already contains a `Users` property with type `IDbSet<ApplicationUser>`. You don't need to add your own `DbSet` for `ApplicationUser`. Remove that line and you're good.

Comment: when I delete it it comes back on run time

Comment: Then you have some *other* error. But the one your question is about is fixed by removing this line. Post a new question with your other error if you need help figuring that one out.

Comment: @ChrisPratt but after remove it,when i want add Controller for ApplicationUser  the Users Property not show in Model Class Box

Comment: Deleting this line then causes build errors as the property is used elsewhere.