# ASP.NET Identity - Multiple object sets per type are not supported (older answers do not work)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am trying to use Entity Framework to access the user table entries in ASP.NET Identity and after scaffolding out a new *Controller* for the `ApplicationUser` class with the `ApplicationDbContext` for the database context, I get the runtime error

> Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets 'ApplicationUsers' and 'Users' can both contain instances of type 'MyApp.Models.ApplicationUser'

Whilst this question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24343246) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25549391/14499007), the solutions do not work for me, as I will explain below.

In the process of scaffolding out the *Controller* and *View* code, Visual Studio also adds the line

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MyApp.Models.ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
```

to the `ApplicationDbContext` class.

Now, I realise that the problem is that the `IdentityDbContext` class from which `ApplicationDbContext` inherits also has a DbSet of type `ApplicationUser` but removing this line (as suggested in answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24343246) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25549391/14499007)) then creates build errors because this property is used in new *Controller* class. For instance;

```
namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    public class NewController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: Admin
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.ApplicationUsers.ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried giving both the property and ApplicationUser a different name but I get the same error.

Is there any way of fixing this problem that does not involve deleting the one line?

Comment: Hi, Martin. Could you show us your ApplicationDbContext class? 
Also, you explained why  you cannot delete the "ApplicationUsers" property, but why can´t you delete the "Users" property ?

Comment: Also the classes of ApplicationUser  and User could be helpful.